# Langchain Prompt Template Change Human/AI Prefix

Tags: langchain

[image]
Currently this Prompt Template looks like this:

Prompt after formatting:
System: You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.
Human: Hi there my friend
AI: Hello! How can I assist you today, my friend?
Human: Not too bad - how are you?

Does somebody know how i can change it to this:

Prompt after formatting:
SYSTEM: You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.
USER: Hi there my friend
ASSISTANT: Hello! How can I assist you today, my friend?
USER: Not too bad - how are you?

Thanks for your help